# Mapping legacy database with possibly a discriminator

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to map a legacy database.  I need to implement what I believe should be a discriminator.  My problem is discriminators only seem to work when there is a column to differentiate or a formula on the current row.  For my case there is no actual differentiator, the data is either joined to one table if it exists, if not, then the other table.  To make things even more complicated the table uses a composite key.
Here's an example (it might be oversimplified as I am making it up):

Given my code

```
public class SomeTable {
  public virtual int DataID { get; set; }
  public virtual int EmployeeOrCustomer { get; set; }
  public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
  public virtual int SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Person {
  public virtual int ID { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person {
  public virtual int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Person {
  public virtual int CustomerNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And my Data

```
-SomeTable-
DataID(K)  EmployeeOrCustomer(K)  SomeValue
     1                      1           100
     1                     22           222

-Employee-
ID            Name      EmployeNumber
 1        Joe Blow              12345

-Customer-
ID             Name    CustomerNumber
22        ACME Inc.              4242
```

My Mappings:

```
<class name="SomeTable" abstract="true">
  <composite-id>
    <key-property name="DataID" />
    <key-property name="EmployeeOrCustomer" />
  </composite-id>
  <property name="SomeValue" />
  <!--   ?????? -->
</class>
<class name="Employee">
  <id name="ID" />
  <Property name="EmployeeNumber">
</Class>
<class name="Customer">
  <id name="ID" />
  <Property name="CustomerNumber">
</Class>
```

What I expect

```
DataID: 1,  SomeValue: 100  Person: { Employee: EmployeeNumber: 12345 }
DataID: 1,  SomeValue: 222, Person: { Customer: CustomerNumber: 4242 }
```

I thought about joining the 2 tables and using the merged tables as a join but the 2 tables differ a lot.  Also, I can't modify the schema so adding a discriminator column is not an option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what you are searching for is union subclass inheritance mapping

```
<class name="Person" abstract="true">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>

  <union-subclass table="Employee" name="Employee">
    <property name="Name"/>
    <property name="EmployeeNumber"/>
  </union-subclass>

  <union-subclass table="Customer" name="Customer">
    <property name="Name"/>
    <property name="CustomerNumber"/>
  </union-subclass>
</class>

<class name="SomeTable" abstract="true">
  <composite-id>
    <key-property name="DataID" />
    <key-many-to-one name="Person" column="EmployeeOrCustomer" />
  </composite-id>
  <property name="SomeValue" />
</class>
```

Note the extra property `EmployeeOrCustomer` is not needed.

Comment: I can't quite get this scenario to work.  Could you post the C# code that would go with it?  I'm getting either the wrong SQL altogether when SomeTable.Person type is set to int.  When I set it to EmployeeOrcustomer as EmployeeOrcustomerType I get a "NHibernate.MappingException : Could not determine type for.." error.  I was also looking at how to use union-subclass and it seems to be good for the case that Employee or Customer would always have same data attached to it (SomeData) but this is not the case.  I just created a brief example to illustrate my problem.

Comment: Looks like you had it pretty close.  I didn't notice <key-reference ...> in the SomeTable mapping.  It looks like it should be <key-many-to-one ...>.  Marked as correct answer.